# jQuery popup form?

Tags: php, jquery, forms, jquery-tools

I have a form which is currently sitting in a division on a php page.

I would like it to do the following:

- User clicks link to bring up form in pop-up division in center of screen
- User fills out the form
- User hits the submit button
- Form closes and brings up another small division with a thank you message which shows for 5 seconds then disappears

What's going to be the easiest way to achieve this?

I currently have jQuery and jQuery Tools scripts on the site in question.

EDIT: I'can't use jquery-ui as that conflicts with jQuery tools accordion.

Comment: This should be very easy to do in jQuery. What have you already tried?

Comment: "What's going to be the easiest way to achieve this?" - By writing code? Seriously, what are you expecting from us? Write it for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a look at this documentation about jQuery UI Dialogs:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/

Have also a look at `Modal Forms` (look at the navigation menu at the right of the page).
Basically, you only set up a form inside of a dialog.
Having that thank you -Dialog show up for a few seconds is also easy by using jquery Dialogs and something like `setTimeout` to close it.

Don't forget to include the jQuery and jQuery UI libraries into your source code. Have a look at some jQuery tutorial first, if you don't know jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

For similar task, I used JQuery UI Dialog

http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-form